# Ext.NET MultiCombo not firing event after de-selecting last item

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ext.net

Below is the razor markup, that i am using to get `Ext.NET MultiCombo` as shown in attached image

```
Html.X().MultiComboFor(x => x.CountryCodes).MultiSelect(true)
    .Editable(false)
    .QueryMode(DataLoadMode.Local)
    .TriggerAction(TriggerAction.All)
    .DisplayField("COUNTRY_DESC")
    .ValueField("COUNTRY_CD")
    .LabelWidth(80)
    .FieldLabel(PR.Resources.IP.IP.Country)
    .Listeners(ls => { ls.Select.Handler = "setCountryCodes();return false;"; ls.Change.Handler = "return false;"; })
    .Store(Html.X().Store()
            .ID("storeListCountryForPTOTR")
        .AutoLoad(false)
                .Model(Html.X().Model()
                .IDProperty("COUNTRY_CD")
    .Fields(
            new ModelField("COUNTRY_CD", ModelFieldType.String) { Mapping = "COUNTRY_CD" },
            new ModelField("COUNTRY_DESC", ModelFieldType.String) { Mapping = "COUNTRY_DESC" }
            )
        )
            .Proxy(Html.X().AjaxProxy()
                    .Url(Url.Action("GetPriceTrendCountryForCountryDropdown", "InternalPricing")).ActionMethods(methods =>
                            methods.Read = HttpMethod.POST
                            ).Reader(Html.X().JsonReader().Root("data"))
            )
)
```

[image]

As shown in markup i am handling `Select` event on checkbox check/uncheck.
but this event is not getting fired when i `Un-Check` remaining item from list.

What could be the reason that MultiCombo is not firing the event for last item uncheck?

Answer (score 0):

The Select event is meant to fire on selecting an item only, not on deselecting.

Probably, MultiCombo's Change event is what you need.